# MVC 4 bundling, bootstrap ie 8 issue, how to resolve?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bundling-and-minification

I am developing an application with MVC 4 and bootstrap.  The application works really well, but on IE 8 the application looks horrible. After doing some googling to fix the issue, I added the

response.src.js

this fixed the ie 8 issues and the application works great in Development mode.

As soon as I push it into production, the application looks horrible again.
I am pretty sure its to do with the bundling and minifcation, as this is a process that happens when I publish it out.   If I take the production site and add the word

```
debug = true
```

the site looks great again in ie8..

anyone else seen this issue? or have any ideas?

anyone?

Comment: When I saw this error once, it was due to the number of stylesheets.  ie 9 and below had a limit of 31 stylesheets, so my ie 8-specific sheet was being ignored (it was the last in the list).

Comment: I don't even have 10 style sheets... so maybe not that.. but thanks for the heads up

Comment: @user2206329 well... turn on optimizations locally (EnableOptimizations) and see if there are any issues with your scripts or styles when they get bundled.

Comment: MikeSmithDev - I am getting the same problem, as soon as I check it with ie8, the site looks horrible.  How can I check to see if there are any issues with mu bundling? does it show error messages etc?

Comment: Does it have the same behaviour in Chrome and FireFox? If it does, hit F12 in Chrome, and take a look at the Console tab that appears, what does it says?